# Close a window with an image on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010

I want to have an image (or a button) that, when the user click on it, it closes the window, like ALT+F4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay...this is an extremely simple operation.

For a Button, handle the Click() event and Close() the Form.  You can simply double click the Button to have the method stub inserted for you.  The exact same thing can be done with a PictureBox:

VB.Net:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

C#:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```